# Non-static method Pager::factory() should not be called statically

Tags: methods, pager, non-static

I am a beginner in php.Whenever i try to implement Pager class in pear i get this error

Non-static method Pager::factory() should not be called statically in D:\xampp\htdocs\sam\temp\youtube_playlist.php on line 21

My code is

```
<?php
        include("header.php");
        include("connect.php");
        //connect to db to get video data
        $qr = mysql_query("SELECT vid FROM videos",$con);
        $data="";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qr))
        {
        $data[]=$row['vid'];
        }

        //pageing       
        require('Pager/Pager.php');
        $pg_op= array(
        'itemData'=>$data,
        'append' => true,
        'perPage' => 3,
        'mode' => 'Sliding',
        'delta' => 2
        );
        $pager = Pager::factory($pg_op);
        $pdata = $pager -> getPageData();
        $plinks = $pager -> getLinks();

            //Display the video
            foreach ($pdata as $vd)
            {
?>


            <iframe width="510" height="265" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $vd; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <?php
                }


                echo "<br />";
                echo $plinks['all'];
                include("footer.php");
            ?>
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue.
This Pager class seems to be outdated. If you still want to use it, just suppress error by prepending the command with @

```
$pager = @Pager::factory($pg_op);
```